# Accessing Field2 in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I'm trying to write a simple little routine to email an attachment stored in an Access 2007 database. For some reason I cannot get the simplest part of it to work.

I get an error saying "User-defined type not defined" on the following line:

```
Dim attachmentField As DAO.Field2
```

Now up to this point I haven't accessed any DAO objects yet, but my assumption was that I only needed to add the relevant reference. Thing is, I seem to have a misconception about what that reference is. I have tried "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library" which made sense, but I'm still getting the same error message. Then I tried 3.5 of the same and then JET and then a few more that made far less sense.

Here's the full listing, in case I missed something else that is real basic. I know it needs an awful lot of cleanup, but I'd like to get it working first.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
  Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
  Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem
  Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  With MailOutLook
    .To = Description.Value
    .Subject = "Confirmation of " & ID.Value

    'Error on the next line
    Dim attachmentField As DAO.Field2
    attachmentField = Recordset("Att")
    attachmentField.SaveToFile "C:\Temp\" & Att.FileName
    Attachments.Add "C:\Temp\" & Att.FileName, olByValue, 1, "Document"

    '.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
    .Send
  End With
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a reference to DAO Version 12 - which supports the new FIELD2 object

Try adding this reference - "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine"

Answer (score -2):

Change the line to

```
 Dim attachmentField As DAO.Field
```

Also, where does the Recordset come from? Where is it being filled with records?

Comment: Nope. I am looking for Field2 - that's what you need to manipulate attachment fields.