# What are the major differences between the Field and Field2 objects in Microsoft Access..?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, dao

I'm looking for some discussion of the differences between the 'Field' and 'Field2' objects in Microsoft Access. I'm using Access 2007 as a front-end to an IBM i-Series AS400 DB2 v6 SQL database.

There is this link, which plainly states the 'Field2' is identical to 'Field', but with additional properties available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257445(v=office.12).aspx. But this doesn't really elaborate on the situations where it should be used.

Also there is this, which states DAO 12 must be referenced to use 'Field2', and shows some code, but again it doesn't elaborate much. It does however show how it's used with Outlook, and I wonder if that's correct or if if a 'Field(1)' would work also: [Accessing Field2 in Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196960/accessing-field2-in-access-2007)

So...what are some reasons to use one over the other..? Are the additional properties only used for newer DB systems..? Or certain software..? Or what..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Access as a front-end to an ODBC data source there should be no functional difference between `DAO.Field` and `DAO.Field2` objects. `Field2` objects have been enhanced to support Access-specific structures like `Attachment` fields.

Comment: Would attachments be like a LOB or BLOB as they are called in other DB systems..? I did read the info on the Attachment property, and these seemed to simply be references to files on disk, rather than binary data stored within the database itself.

Comment: Access has long had a BLOB field type (named `OLE Object` for historical reasons), but it also added an `Attachment` field type in Access 2007. The files in an `Attachment` field are actually stored in compressed form within the database. Details [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd).